# Why is the adjectival form of “governor” gubernatorial?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, adjectives

Why isn’t the adjectival form “governatorial” or something similar? Why did “gubernatorial” become the standard and accepted adjective for “governor”? *Govern*’s adjective is *governable* and not *gubernable*. *Government*’s adjective is *governmental* and not *gubernmental*. Why then is *governor*’s adjective *gubernatorial*?

Comment: @sumelic It may be similar, but there are no answers as to why the adjectival form is “gubernatorial” and not “governatorial” (or something similar).

Comment: Hmm ... as the accepted answer says, "gubernatorial [...] was formed directly from the Latin root gubernator, hence the difference." And some people do use "governatorial", although it's less common. Doesn't that seem like as much of an answer to your question as you're likely to get? It's hard to see how somebody could give a definite explanation for why "governatorial" didn't start out as a more common adjective than "gubernatorial".

Comment: @sumelic It’s funny because I looked in most accredited dictionaries (including the OED) but I could not find any word such as “governatorial.” And yet you say some people use it.

Comment: Hey, I didn't say it was a common word! (Or a dictionary-recognized word. You can read about one advocate of it in this 2010 Jan Freeman article: ["No love for 'Gov?"
Why we hate ‘gubernatorial’"](http://archive.boston.com/bostonglobe/ideas/articles/2010/10/10/why_we_hate_gubernatorial/)) F'x's answer to that question links to the Google Ngram Viewer chart, and you can find a few examples of its use if you search for it on Google Books.

Comment: @sumelic That’s a great article—I read it. I suppose that’s as close to an answer I’ll get...

Comment: I see. Maybe you could link to it in your question to provide some more background for other people. Thanks for editing, by the way--I do find your comparison to *governable* and *governmental* interesting, and I'm still thinking about whether these are comparable examples of related words. Another word that seems like *governmental* is *judg(e)mental,* which is not something like "judicamental" even though the adjective corresponding to *judge* is *judicial.* I think *-mental* became established as an adjective ending that used for adjectives related to any kind of *-ment* nouns.

Comment: @sumelic That’s a good point about “judgmental.” I would say that “judge” can be used as a noun or a verb, so ***a judge*** has ***judicial*** power but ***judging someone*** is called ***judgment***. “Governor,” however, is always a noun, so the adjectival form has to be the same for it... Does that make any sense? (If it doesn’t, blame my tiredness...)

Comment: I agree that *judg(e)ment(al)* is built on the verb *judge* rather than on the noun *judge,* but I don't think that fits with the idea that the adjectival form of the noun *governor* can't change. It seems like both sets of words support the idea that adjectives built on verbs (like *judgemental, governmental,* and *governable*) are less likely, not more likely to switch to a Latin form of the root. (Although there are also examples of verb-based adjectives that do show this kind of variant base, like *destructible.*)

Comment: @sumelic I hear that.

Comment: Now I want to know why we don't use His/Her Honor the Guberner.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Don’t we all!

Comment: I don't see an answer here, and I should see even deleted answers. What happened to it?

Comment: @JasonBassford What do you mean?

Comment: @TheWordsmith Never mind! The referents of "the accepted answer" and "bob's answer" were in the *other* question—not something that had ever been given as an answer *here*.  ;)